# Structure for SQL MERGE statement in snowflake?

Tags: sql, merge, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

According to the snowflake [docs](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/sql/merge.html) for the merge statement, I would think the following query would work:

```
MERGE INTO TEST_TABLE AS T 
USING
    (SELECT * FROM (VALUES ('name1', 56.0), ('name2', 29.0))) AS S (USERNAME, BALANCE)
ON T.USERNAME = S.USERNAME
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT
        (USERNAME, BALANCE)
    VALUES
        (S.USERNAME, S.BALANCE)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET
        USERNAME = S.USERNAME, BALANCE = S.BALANCE;
```

However I get the error

```
SQL compilation error: error line 4 at position 16
invalid identifier 'S.USERNAME'
```

I have also tried aliasing the source data using a WITH statement like this

```
WITH S (USERNAME, BALANCE) AS (
    SELECT * FROM (VALUES ('name1', 56.0), ('name2', 29.0))
)
MERGE INTO TEST_TABLE AS T 
USING S
ON T.USERNAME = S.USERNAME
.
.
.
```

but this yeilds a different error

```
SQL compilation error:
syntax error line 4 at position 0 unexpected 'MERGE'.
```

Can someone help me better understand both the docs, and what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Here's some code we having that runs in production:

```
MERGE INTO ${db_name~}.${schema~}.AGGREGATION_WATERMARK dst
USING ${db_name~}.${schema~}.EVENT_WATERMARK src ON dst.unit_id = src.unit_id
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (unit_id, time) VALUES (src.unit_id, src.time)
WHEN MATCHED AND src.time < dst.time THEN UPDATE
    SET dst.time = src.time,
    dst._update_time_utc = TO_TIMESTAMP_NTZ(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
```

Maybe the column naming is not working for MERGE, but if you change the inner sub-select from:

```
SELECT * FROM (VALUES ('name1', 56.0), ('name2', 29.0))
```

to name the columns in there, like:

```
SELECT temp.* FROM VALUES ('name1', 56.0), ('name2', 29.0) temp (USERNAME, BALANCE)
```

then when you alias it to `S`  it should work?

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT temp.* FROM VALUES ('name1', 56.0), ('name2', 29.0) temp (USERNAME, BALANCE)) S;
```

the outer `select *` is just there to show it working outside the content of the `MERGE` `USING`

Comment: SELECT *, SELECT S.*, and SELECT USERNAME, BALANCE all work for simple retrieving values, but none seem to be properly aliasing the source table for the MERGE command.

Comment: It rather sounds like you have found a bug.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few slight differences, but I believe this should work.

```
 WITH S (USERNAME, BALANCE) AS (
     SELECT USERNAME, BALANCE 
     FROM (VALUES ('name1', 56.0), ('name2', 29.0)) AS S (USERNAME, BALANCE)
 )
 MERGE TEST_TABLE AS T 
 USING S
 ON T.USERNAME = S.USERNAME
 WHEN MATCHED THEN
 UPDATE
 SET T.USERNAME = S.USERNAME
    ,T.BALANCE = S.BALANCE
 WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
 INSERT (USERNAME, BALANCE)
 VALUES (S.USERNAME, S.BALANCE);
```

Answer (score 0):

As you have found, Snowflake handles column aliases *on table aliases* incorrectly.

Compare (fails with your error)

```
SELECT o.one
FROM (SELECT 1) o(one);
```

with (runs successfully)

```
SELECT o.one
FROM (SELECT 1 AS one) o;
```

I suspect if you expand the `SELECT *` to a named list of columns, and change `AS S (USERNAME, BALANCE)` to simply `AS S`, then the query will compile.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if someone still trying to have this worked. I was here searching for a solution but could get the below query working for me:

```
MERGE INTO "<database_name>"."<schema_name>"."<target_table>" AS "TARGET" 
USING (SELECT "SOURCE".* FROM VALUES 
          ('value_1a','value_1b', 'value_1c'),
          ('value_2a','value_2b', 'value_2c') 
"SOURCE"("column_a", "column_b", "column_c")) "SOURCE" 
ON "SOURCE"."column_a"= "TARGET"."column_a" WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE SET "TARGET"."column_b"="SOURCE"."column_b";
```